# Child components saves state even when I update parent state

Tags: reactjs

My child component has a state that is an empty array called `answers`.

That array is getting populated with an index of `li` item that contains input that can be either radio or checkbox. So if you have 4 checkbox li elements and you click on First and Last, the array will contain 0 and 3.

When I click "next" ,that array is passed as argument to a function that is passed from parent component and that function adds that array from child to parent state.

Since parent state is getting re-rendered I assumed my child component when created again will have default state that is empty array but the state it has is actually same as before I called next function, say 0 and 3.

My constructor in child also doesn't get called 2nd time. You can see it [here](https://github.com/nhrnjic/Quizmaker/blob/7eab2a24c0f62cada4ec3af93c317f74308d9ebf/QuizMaker/Web/Scripts/Run.jsx).

Answer (score 0):

When you passing the callback functions to child `Question`, those functions were not bound with parent `Run` object. Thus when `Question` called those functions, the self-ref variable `this` was `undefined`.

Try change this:

```
...
onPrev = {this.onPrev}
onNext = {this.onNext}
...
```

To:

```
...
onPrev = {this.onPrev.bind(this)}
onNext = {this.onNext.bind(this)}
...
```

There must be an error thrown out in browser console. If this doesn't solve your problem maybe you can post the error from console too.